# Why Views Slideshow JCarousel plugin isn't available on view format settings?

Tags: 7, views

I've installed:

- Views Slideshow
- Views Slideshow Cycle
- Views Slideshow Carousel

All required libraries are available. Status reports page is green.

I want to create slideshow view. I choose slideshow format, but on settings I have only Cycle as available slideshow type.

What can be wrong?

Comment: uninstall it and then try to use different version.

Comment: Do you mean [Views Slideshow JCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. jQuery Cycle is the default library used by the Views Slideshow Cycle module.

Look instead at "Widgets" on the format settings screen. The relevant configuration options will appear by selecting "Pager" under either *Top Widgets* or *Bottom widgets*.

From the [Views Slideshow JCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel) project page:

> Currently provides a JCarousel **pager widget**.

and

> Under the Format heading, click "format" and select "slideshow". You
>   should now be able to select and configure your jcarousel slideshow.
>   Pager options are on this configuration screen, not under views "pager
>   settings". To decide where you want your pager to go, you can tick the
>   pager widget checkbox beneath the area you wish to show it. your
>   choices are "top" or "bottom" of carousel.

**Note:** If using Views Slideshow Cycle, you will need to download the [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin.

Comment: Important thing: cycle plugin need to be enabled too.

Comment: The *Views Slideshow Cycle* submodule requires it, so you'd get loud warnings on your status page if you didn't have the plugin. That info really should be on the project page, though. Anyway, thanks for selecting my answer. :)

Comment: My status page was green so that's why I had no idea what is the problem

Comment: Weird. It's right here: [root/contrib/views_slideshow_cycle/views_slideshow_cycle.install](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_slideshow/tree/contrib/views_slideshow_cycle/views_slideshow_cycle.install). Maybe there's a bug.

Comment: I have trying different versions so maybe this in the reason

Comment: I've added a note in my answer.