# Why jCarousel displays only single item?

Tags: 7, javascript, views

This question is related to: [Why Views Slideshow JCarousel plugin isn't available on view format settings?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169575/why-views-slideshow-carousel-plugin-isnt-available-on-view-format-settings)

I've managed to carousel started working but I have only single item visible at a time. However number of Visible Items is 8 and I have 10 pictures. So AFAIC displays 8 pictures at a time

Modules
- jquery_update
- views slideshow jcarousel 7.x-2.x-dev

and jcarousel: https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/releases/tag/0.3.1

My widget[image]

Comment: What does your pager configuration look like? (Format: Slideshow > Settings)

Comment: Because dev jcarousel forces me to use jquery_update, I resigned with this module at all.

Comment: anyway I've integrated jcarousel without using views slideshow at all.